# Navigating Local Directories using Cordova

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I am trying to access and navigate through the local directories of the phone but all I can do upto now is list the root directory but not able to traverse through it.. I am getting stucked on how to set the FileSystem.root to the selected directory so that I can navigate ..

below is the code that I tried which list all the directories in list

```
//
var diary = angular.module('DiaryController', []);

diary.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$cordovaMedia', '$ionicPlatform', function($scope, $cordovaMedia, $ionicPlatform) {

//View File System Of Android
$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess);
});

function onFileSystemSuccess (fileSystem) {
    console.log(fileSystem);
    var DirectoryEntry = fileSystem.root.createReader();
    DirectoryEntry.readEntries(onReadSuccess);
}

function onReadSuccess (entries) {
    console.log(entries);
    $scope.directories = [];

    for (i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        $scope.directories.push(entries[i]);
    }

}


}]);
```

Comment: Have you tried [`fileSystem.root.getDirectory("...", {}, success, failure)`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#DirectoryEntry_getdirectory)? (I don't have a Cordova instance to test on, so I'm hesitant to post an answer.)

Comment: What I actually wanted is to do directory navigation like a file browser .. I do not understand what to pass in the path field of `getDirectory` method